# CKEDITOR - get Attribute from Parent when clicked on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to get the value of the attribute `"data-time-start"` when I click on an element in CKEDITOR body.

My FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/7hvrxw2c/25/

HTML :

```
<div id="ckeditor_block">
    <textarea id="editor1"> <span class="sub" id="sub1" data-time-start="0">Hello </span>
       <span class="sub" id="sub2" data-time-start="2">My </span>
       <span class="sub" id="sub3" data-time-start="6"><strong>Name</strong></span>
       <span class="sub" id="sub4" data-time-start="8"><strong><span style="color:#800080;">was</span></strong></span> 
       <span class="sub" id="sub5" data-time-start="12">Zoob</span>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var textarea;

$(document).ready(function () {
    textarea = $('#ckeditor_block').find('textarea').attr('id');
    ckeditor_init();
});

function ckeditor_init() {
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea, {
        language: 'fr',
        allowedContent: true
    });

    var editorInstance = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
    editorInstance.on('contentDom', function () {
        editorInstance.editable().attachListener(this.document, 'click', function (event) {
            console.log(event.data.getTarget().data('time-start'));
        });
    });
}
```

Works for words `My` and `Zoob` But it return null if I click on text with `style color` or `strong` or whatever...

I tried to add a condition like this but no way...

```
if (element.$.className === "st") {
   cursor = event.data.getTarget().data("time-start");
} else {
   cursor = event.data.getTarget().$.parentElement.offsetParent.firstElementChild;
}
```

How to do that please ? thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I find value from jquery [***closest()***](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method

```
editorInstance.on('contentDom', function () {
    editorInstance.editable().attachListener(this.document, 'click', function (event) {
        var el = event.data.$.target.closest("span.sub");
        console.log($(el).data('time-start'));
    });
});
```

View this [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/7hvrxw2c/26/)